# Set MySQL variable without using a semicolon

Tags: mysql

I was kindly given this code suggestion for getting the ranking of each person by score, is there a way of declaring the var without using a semicolon? I found one way of declaring from within the query but I couldn't get it to work when using a sub-query like that below:

```
SET @rank := 0;
SELECT a.name, 
   a.AvScore, 
   @rank := @rank + 1 
FROM   (SELECT name, 
           Avg(score) AS AvScore 
    FROM   results 
    GROUP  BY name) a
ORDER  BY a.AvScore
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try it like that

```
    SELECT a.name, 
           a.AvScore, 
           @rank := @rank + 1 
    FROM   (SELECT name, 
           Avg(score) AS AvScore ,(SELECT @rank :=0) v
    FROM   results 

    GROUP  BY name) a
    ORDER  BY a.AvScore
```

Comment: I'm still trying now but I'm not getting any values back. The command runs without error but there's no output. Might just be my ineptitude with MySQL...

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to change the delimiter (e.g. to something like this `//`) you should do it like this:

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> SET @rank := 0 //
```

MySQL needs a delimiter identification so that it will able to delimit your multiple sentence, otherwise it can be as well a single sentence which do not apply to the constraint rules checking for correct syntax.

**Update**

As a response to the comment (OP is interested to execute multiple queries from the same statement once), although i am not familiar with PHP, and there is `addBatch` method for JDBC that enables to execute multiple quires for single statement,

it seems that in php `mysqli->multi_query` does the same.

For the presented case @echo_me has presented an elegant solution to avoid multiple queries, for others you should consider multi_query.

Comment: Thanks for tip about Delimiter, I'd read about that earlier but it's not quite what I need to do. I specifically need to remove the multi-query aspect of it...

Comment: @user2000718, do you wish to do it as a result of io constraints from jdbc statements?

Comment: Very close! It's for use in a legacy website running PHP and Mysql instead of MySQLi. Otherwise I could just use mysqli_multi_query...maybe use a join in the two querys from within PHP?

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP, but for JDBC you may use `Statement.addBatch` method to append several queries into one statement and execute it at once.

Comment: @user2000718, i have updated the answer, so that in future you would know how to execute multiple queries for single statement.

Comment: Wihtin PHP, MySQLi and Mysql are not the same thing. As stated, I'm having to find a fix for a legacy site that is not running MySQLi and therefore I cannot run mysqli_multi_query.